# Is there an algorithm to find all the common sub-sequences of items in 2 List<List<int>>, PRESERVING THE ORDER?

Tags: c#, list, int

There are 2 Lists.
I have to find all the sub-sequences of integers contained in BOTH the List>, where the ORDER IS PRESERVED.

```
List<List<int>> listOfLists1 = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 5, 7, 8 };
listOfLists1.Add(list1);
listOfLists1.Add(list2);

List<List<int>> listOfLists2 = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> list3 = new List<int>() { 5, 1, 2, 5 };
List<int> list4 = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 7, 8 };
List<int> list5 = new List<int>() { 5, 6 };
listOfLists2.Add(list3);
listOfLists2.Add(list4);
listOfLists2.Add(list5);
```

The expected result is:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
1, 2 
3, 4 
4, 5 
5, 6 
5, 7 
7, 8 
3, 4, 5 
5, 7, 8
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there an algorithm I am not aware of that can be employed to solve this   kind of problem? (this is the main question).
2. Are there other kinds of data structures instead of

   List of lists of type T

and

```
List of type T
```

that are more appropriate for solving this problem?

I solved it by creating all the sub-sequences of each of the Lists in the listOfLists1 and separately of each of the Lists in the listOfLists2, preserving the order of the items and then I found the ones contained in both (the common ones).

It seems that the step of creating all the sub-sequences is superfluous. There should be a more efficient way.
Thank you in advance.

I am sorry but I seem to be unable to write the 2 kinds of lists legible.
what I mean are: List of lists of type T and List of type T.
I hope now it will be more clear.

The method I use to find all the sub-sequences is:

```
private static List<List<T>> FindAllSubSequencesOfConsecutiveCommonItems<T
>(T[] commonItemsArrangemet)
{
    List<List<T>> allSequencesOfConsecutiveCommonItems = new List<List<T>>();
    List<T> sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems = new List<T>();
    T currentCommonItem;
    for (int i = 0; i < commonItemsArrangemet.Length; i++)
        {
             currentCommonItem = commonItemsArrangemet[i];
             if (currentCommonItem != null)
             {
                 sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems.Add(currentCommonItem );
             {
             else
             {
                 if (sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems.Count > 0
                 {
                     allSequencesOfConsecutiveCommonItems.Add(sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems);
                     sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems = new List<T>();
                 }
             }
         }
     if (sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems.Count > 0
     {               
         allSequencesOfConsecutiveCommonItems.Add(sequenceOfConsecutiveCommonItems);
     }

      return allSequencesOfConsecutiveCommonItems;
}
```

The method that creates all the sub-sequences of a sequence of items is:

```
public static List<List<T>> CreateAllSubSequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder<T>(List<List<T>> allItems, int minimumSequenceLength)
{
    if (allItems == null || allItems.Count == 0 || minimumSequenceLength <= 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    List<List<T>> sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int currentList = 0; currentList < allItems.Count; currentList++)
    {
        List<T> itemsInOneList = allItems[currentList];
        List<List<T>> sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsFromOneList = CreateAllSequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder(itemsInOneList, minimumSequenceLength);
        sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder.AddRange(sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsFromOneList);
    }

    return sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder;
}

public static List<List<T>> CreateAllSequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder<T>(List<T> itemsInOneList, int minimumSequenceLength)
{
    if (itemsInOneList == null || itemsInOneList.Count == 0 || minimumSequenceLength <= 0)
    {
         return null;
    }
    List<List<T>> sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsInOneList.Count; i++)
    {
        List<T> currentSequenceOfConsecutiveItems = new List<T>();
        int j = i;
        while (j < itemsInOneList.Count)
        {
            T currentItem = itemsInOneList[j];
            currentSequenceOfConsecutiveItems .Add(currentItem);
            if (currentSequenceOfConsecutiveItems.Count >= minimumSequenceLength)
            {
                sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder.Add(currentSequenceOfConsecutiveItems);
                currentSequenceOfConsecutiveItems = new List<T>(currentSequenceOfConsecutiveItems);
            }
            j++;
        }
   }

    return sequencesOfConsecutiveItemsPreservingSequentialOrder;
}
```

Comment: Still unclear why do you need a `List<List<int>>`. For me, it looks like you want to find all common subsequences of two `List<int>`. Did I get it clear?

Comment: Please show us your work. "There should be a more efficient way." is not a good basis for a question.

Comment: I copied your lists and worked out an (inefficient) solution involving turning everything into strings, and I can say **there is no easy and "quick" algorithm existing** for your case. At best you can combine a few existing algorithms (get all sub-sequences, compare intersections, etc) of the best time complexity. As for your second question, as far as I can tell, there is no single method which does not depend on the types involved, at best some solutions (like the one I came up with) would work for `int`, `string`, `decimal`, etc (all those which can be converted to string and back).

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev If there is an efficient algorithm that finds all common sub-sequences of 2 List<int> PRESERVING THEIR SEQUENTIAL ORDER, please let me know.

Comment: How do you call `FindAllSubSequencesOfConsecutiveCommonItems`? (Btw. there are two `{` where there should be `}` at the "end" of two `if` blocks)

Comment: @Corak I am sorry if a mistake sneaked in. I cannot find it now by looking at the code, because it wraps around. I did not copy and paste but I copied visually from one computer to another, as the code runs on a computer that has no internet access.