# ALL subsequences of common, CONSECUTIVE items in two List<int>

Tags: c#, list

A few days ago I posted a question:
Is there an algorithm to find ALL the sub-sequences of common, CONSECUTIVE items in 2 List>, PRESERVING THE ORDER?
Yeldar Kurmangaliyev, quite insightfully pointed out that what I actually need is:
all common subsequences of two Lists.
Since I did not get any answer to the previous question, I would like to know whether there exists an efficient algorithm to find:
ALL the sub-sequences of common, CONSECUTIVE items in two Lists 
or do I have to try to come up with the best algorithm I am able to.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The shortest subsequence would be just a single item. That means you can just get all items from one List that are also contained in the other List. That shouldn't be to hard

Comment: _or do I have to try to come up with the best algorithm I am able to_ - Yes, this is what usually you will do before asking questions here ;) and if you will not get result you required - you will ask more specific question here.

Comment: I assume you're looking for something like this? 'var CommonList = TestList1.Intersect(TestList2)' from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520006/find-common-items-across-multiple-lists-in-c-sharp . All it took was a simple google to find it. Unless ofcourse, I misunderstood what you want. Regarding efficiency, I don't know if it is efficient enough for you, or if there is something more efficient, but it seems to be supported through Linq, and I usually trust Linq native methods to be somewhat reliable performance-wise (if you don't do weird things, ofcourse)

Comment: @Fabio As you probably noticed, I did not ask for a ready made solution! I merely asked whether someone knows an efficient algorithm that already exists, so that I do not have to reinvent the weel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an algorithm to find all the common sub-sequences of items in 2 List<List<int>>, PRESERVING THE ORDER?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137984/is-there-an-algorithm-to-find-all-the-common-sub-sequences-of-items-in-2-listli)

Comment: @ RomanoZumbé I do not need only the shortest common subsequence, but all of them.

Comment: @Philipp The post you are pointing at is also mine. I mentioned this in the current question. I just did not receive an answer.

Comment: @Bart Unfortunately, the List.Intersect returns all the items common to both the lists, not only those that are consecutive and not preserving the order of the items in the lists.

Comment: @Bart Also the post you sent me to has solutions that do not take into consideration items consecutiveness and their order within the lists they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Quite some time passed since I asked the question:
I would like to know whether there exists an efficient algorithm to find: ALL the sub-sequences of common, CONSECUTIVE items in two Lists.
In all this time, nobody suggested any algorithm that solves this problem, therefore I conclude that no known algorithm exists, so I developed one myself.
I decided to share it here for a double reason:
1. In order to receive feedback.
Having no formal theoretical computer science education, I would greatly appreciate any suggestion for the algorithm efficiency and performance improvement.
2. In the hope that it will help someone in the future.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Problem statement:
    ///     Given two lists: list1 and list2, find all the sequences of common consecutive items in the two lists.
    /// 
    /// General considerations:
    ///     1. No constraints or limitations are imposed on the two lists, so the lists may contain any number of items, even a very large number of items, therefore the 
    ///        efficiency and performance of the algorithm are paramount.
    ///     2. No constraints or limitations are imposed on the items themselves, so the tow lists may contain any type of items: items of value type or items of reference 
    ///        type.
    ///        For items of reference type, the different references to the common items, stored in the two lists must point to the same memory address (to the same object) 
    ///        and not to two objects who are considered equal by virtue of some properties they have, which happen to have equal values at the moment.
    ///     3. The problem asks for SEQUENCES of items. In this context, a single item may be considered a sequence (an atrophied sequence of a single item).
    ///     4. The problem asks for sequences of COMMON items, so it makes sense to work only with the items contained in both the lists, ignoring all other items (the ones 
    ///        contained only on one of the lists and not contained in the other list) in order to improve the efficiency of the algorithm.
    ///     5. The problem asks for sequences of common CONSECUTIVE items, so the order of the items in of the lists is important. The only items of interest are those common 
    ///        items that form sequences of consecutive items, contained in BOTH the lists and not only in one of them (items that are consecutive in both the lists).
    ///        
    /// The algorithm:
    /// Step 1: Find all the common items of the 2 lists.
    ///         The most efficient way to find all the common items of 2 lists is their intersection:
    ///                  public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
    ///         Enumerable.Intersect<TSource> Method: 
    ///         (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)
    ///         Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.
    ///         The result is an IEnumerable<T> whose distinct elements appear in both IEnumerable<TSource> that are intersected.
    /// Step 2: Find all the sequences of common consecutive items in list1.
    /// Step 3: Find all the sequences of common consecutive items in list2.
    /// Step 4: Find all the sequences of common consecutive items contained in both: list1 and in list2 (the common sequences).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list1"></param>
    /// <param name="list2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static List<List<T>> FindAllSequencesOfCommonConsecutiveItemsInTwoLists<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)
    {
        // Step 1: Find all the common items of the 2 lists.
        HashSet<T> list1AsHashSet = new HashSet<T>(list1);
        HashSet<T> list2AsHashSet = new HashSet<T>(list2);
        list1AsHashSet.IntersectWith(list2AsHashSet);
        HashSet<T> allCommonItems = new HashSet<T>(list1AsHashSet);

        // Step 2: Find all the sequences of common consecutive items in list1.
        List<List<T>> sequencesOfCommonConsecutiveItemsInList1 = FindAllSequencesOfConsecutiveItemsInListFormedOnlyWithItemsContainedAlsoInSourceItems(list1, allCommonItems);
        // Step 3: Find all the sequences of common consecutive items in list2.
        List<List<T>> sequencesOfCommonConsecutiveItemsInList2 = FindAllSequencesOfConsecutiveItemsInListFormedOnlyWithItemsContainedAlsoInSourceItems(list2, allCommonItems);
        // Step 4: Find all the sequences of common consecutive items contained in both: list1 and in list2 (the common sequences).
        List<List<T>> commonSequencesOfConsecutiveItems = FindCommonSequencesInTwoListsOfLists(sequencesOfCommonConsecutiveItemsInList1, sequencesOfCommonConsecutiveItemsInList2);

        return commonSequencesOfConsecutiveItems;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> FindAllSequencesOfConsecutiveItemsInListFormedOnlyWithItemsContainedAlsoInSourceItems<T>(List<T> list, HashSet<T> sourceItems)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count == 0 || sourceItems == null || sourceItems.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<List<T>> allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList = new List<List<T>>(); /* Holds all the sequences of consecutive items in the list, formed only of items that are also 
                                                                                   * contained in the HashSet sourceItems. 
                                                                                   */
        List<T> sequenceOfConsecutiveItems = null; // Holds a single sequence of consecutive items in the list, formed only of items that are also contained in the HashSet sourceItems.
        HashSet<T> uniqueSequenceStartingItems = new HashSet<T>(); /* This HashSet holds all the items that start a sequence of consecutive items. 
                                                                    * It makes sure that only a single instance of each sequence of items is saved in the List of Lists - no duplicate 
                                                                    * sequences: no two sequences containing the same items in the same order.
                                                                    */
        T currentItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            sequenceOfConsecutiveItems = new List<T>();
            currentItem = list[i];
            T nextItem;
            if (sourceItems.Contains(currentItem))
            {
                if (uniqueSequenceStartingItems.Add(currentItem)) /* If it is possible to add currentItem to the HashSet uniqueSequenceStartingItems, it is the first occurrence of this 
                                                                   * specific item.
                                                                   */
                {
                    sequenceOfConsecutiveItems.Add(currentItem); /* Form a new list containing the new atrophied sequence of consecutive items formed of the single item currentItem, as 
                                                                  * it is this item's first occurrence and so this sequence is the first instance.
                                                                  */
                    allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList.Add(sequenceOfConsecutiveItems); /* Add the new atrophied sequence of consecutive items formed of the single item currentItem 
                                                                                           * to the List of Lists allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList, that will contain all the 
                                                                                           * sequences of consecutive items in the list, formed only of items that are also contained in 
                                                                                           * the HashSet sourceItems. 
                                                                                           */
                    sequenceOfConsecutiveItems = new List<T>(sequenceOfConsecutiveItems); /* Build a new instance of the list sequenceOfConsecutiveItems, already containing the single 
                                                                                           * item currentItem, which starts a new sequence of consecutive items in the list.
                                                                                           * This sequence will be added to the List of Lists allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList only 
                                                                                           * if at least one additional consecutive item in the list will be found, and this item is 
                                                                                           * also contained in the HashSet sourceItems. 
                                                                                           */               
                    bool itemNotContainedInSourceItemsEncountered = false;
                    int j = i;
                    while (j < list.Count - 1 && !itemNotContainedInSourceItemsEncountered) /* Loop through all the adjacent items of currentItem in search of items that are also contained 
                                                                                             * in the HashSet sourceItems. 
                                                                                             */
                    {
                        if (j < list.Count - 1)
                        {
                            nextItem = list[j + 1];
                            if (sourceItems.Contains(nextItem)) // An additional consecutive item was found, which is also contained in the HashSet sourceItems. 
                            {
                                sequenceOfConsecutiveItems.Add(nextItem); // Add this item to the sequence that already contains at least one item.
                                allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList.Add(sequenceOfConsecutiveItems); /* Add the new sequence of consecutive items to the List of 
                                                                                                       * Lists allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList. 
                                                                                                       */
                                sequenceOfConsecutiveItems = new List<T>(sequenceOfConsecutiveItems); /* Build a new instance of the list sequenceOfConsecutiveItems, which already contains 
                                                                                                       * some consecutive items in the list where all these items are also contained in the 
                                                                                                       * HashSet sourceItems.
                                                                                                       */        
                            }
                            else /* Here the sequence of consecutive items in the list which are also contained in the HashSet sourceItems ends, as this item is not contained in the HashSet 
                                  * sourceItems.
                                  */
                            {
                                itemNotContainedInSourceItemsEncountered = true; 
                                sequenceOfConsecutiveItems = new List<T>(); // Create a new instance of the List sequenceOfConsecutiveItems, for the remaining items in the list.
                            }
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return allSequencesOFConsecutiveItemsInList;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> FindCommonSequencesInTwoListsOfLists<T>(List<List<T>> sequencesOfItemsInList1, List<List<T>> sequencesOfItemsInList2)
    {
        List<List<T>> commonSequencesOfConsecutiveItems = new List<List<T>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < sequencesOfItemsInList1.Count; i++)
        {
            List<T> currentSequenceInList1 = sequencesOfItemsInList1[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < sequencesOfItemsInList2.Count; j++)
            {
                List<T> currentSequenceInList2 = sequencesOfItemsInList2[j];
                if (currentSequenceInList1.SequenceEqual(currentSequenceInList2))
                {
                    commonSequencesOfConsecutiveItems.Add(currentSequenceInList1);
                }
            }
        }

        return commonSequencesOfConsecutiveItems;
    }
```